# Android jodatime, is it possible to execute a piece of code after set duration?

Tags: android, jodatime

What would be the best way to run a piece of code, lets say every minute? Using jodatime..
How would I do that?

Would not like to use Timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need jodatime:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable code = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
        // then queue the runnable again
        Outerclass.this.handler.postDelayed(code, 60000L);
        }
    };
// ...
this.handler.postDelayed(this.gpsNotUpdatingCheck, 60000L); // delay one minute
```

Here is more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html